# Why does Apple's implementation of KVO use subclassing instead of swizzling?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, objective-c-runtime

In Apple's [Key-Value Observing Implementation Details document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html), it says the implementation creates a subclass to forward setter methods. The subclass replaces the original class.

Why not just use `method_exchangeImplementations()` to swizzle the methods? Why is creating a subclass necessary？

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because when you swizzle a method, you change the method for **all instances** of the class. A KVO-notifying setter is more expensive than a non-KVO-notifying setter, so you only want to use the KVO-notifying setter for instances that are actually observed, not for all instances of the class.

What does a KVO-notifying property setter method have to do? At a minimum, it has to check whether there are any KVO observers registered for the property, using [`[self observationInfo]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414009-observationinfo?language=objc#). So that's a guaranteed extra message send. In addition, by default, the `observationInfo` is stored in a thread-safe global hash table, so the KVO-compliant setter has to acquire a lock and perform a hash lookup—just to find out if there are any KVO observers registered.

If you swizzle the property setter, then **every** instance of the class has to pay this price on **every** use of the setter, even if only a tiny fraction of the class instances actually have observers registered.

Apple's KVO implementation creates a KVO-notifying subclass instead. When you register a KVO observer on an instance of a class, it changes the class of **that single instance** to the KVO-notifying subclass. So only the instances that are actually observed have to use the more expensive KVO-notifying setter.

Comment: It, effectively, swizzles the class.